# Format Issuer Output

Tags: powershell, ssl

In the following code as you can see I'm willing to gather informations about SSL certificates but I have two problems with the format that the fields `Issuer` and `Usages` come up with.
The first field `Issuer` fir example shows me results like these:

> O=VMware Installer
>
> CN=Microsoft Development Root Certificate Authority 2014, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

what I want is to have as results

> VMware Installer
>
> Microsoft Development Root Certificate Authority 2014

For the second field `Usages`, I have for example the following output

> DataEncipherment, KeyEncipherment, DigitalSignature
>
> Value             FriendlyName
>
> -----             ------------
>
> 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authentication

What I want to show is :

> DataEncipherment, KeyEncipherment, DigitalSignature,Server Authentication

This is my script:

```
  $CertPath = "Cert:\LocalMachine\"
  $CertsDetail = Get-ChildItem -Path $CertPath -Recurse |`
        Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer -ne $true } |`
        ForEach-Object {
              $Usages = foreach ($key in $_.Extensions) {
                    if ($key.KeyUsages) {
                          $key.KeyUsages
                    }
              }         
              [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Issuer  = $_.Issuer
                    Subject = $_.Subject
                    Usages  = ($Usages | Out-String).Trim()
                    #Usages = $Usages -join ';'
              }
        }
  $CertsDetail
  $CertsDetail | Where-Object { $_.Usages -ne "" } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\SECnology\Data\Utilities\Certificate_State.csv'
```

Comment: Can you show us what the outcome of the `Usages` field is and what your desired output from that would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps doing like below would give you the format you are after:

```
$CertPath = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\'             #'# dummy comment to correct code-highlighting in SO
$CertsDetail = Get-ChildItem -Path $CertPath -Recurse | Where-Object { !$_.PsIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
    $Usages = ($_.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.KeyUsages}).KeyUsages
    if ($Usages) {
        # get at most two parts out of the $_.Issuer string
        $issuer = '{0}, {1}' -f ([regex] 'O=([^,]+)').Match($_.Issuer).Groups[1].Value, 
                                ([regex] 'CN=([^,]+)').Match($_.Issuer).Groups[1].Value
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Issuer  = $issuer.Trim(", ")
            Subject = $_.Subject
            Usages  = $Usages.ToString() -replace ',', ';'
        }
    }
}

$CertsDetail | Format-List
$CertsDetail | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\SECnology\Data\Utilities\Certificate_State.csv'
```

Trying this on my (Windows 7) machine, it gives me output like

```
Issuer  : Microsoft Root Authority
Subject : CN=Microsoft Enforced Licensing Intermediate PCA, OU=Copyright (c) 1999 Microsoft Corp., O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Usages  : CrlSign; KeyCertSign; DigitalSignature

Issuer  : The USERTRUST Network, UTN-USERFirst-Hardware
Subject : CN=www.google.com, OU=PlatinumSSL, OU=Hosted by GTI Group Corporation, OU=Tech Dept., O=Google Ltd., STREET=Sea Village 10, L=English, S=Florida, PostalCode=38477, C=US
Usages  : KeyEncipherment; DigitalSignature
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but there still one thing some `Issuer` starts with `"` , how can I also delete them

Comment: @mamadou You could do `Issuer  = $issuer.Trim(', "')` to also remove the quote character.